# How can I run an interesting council meeting?

Tags: campaign-settings, encounter-design, science-fiction

### The Story so Far

The end is nigh for planet earth! The sun is running out of fuel and life on earth only has about 100-500 years before it gets burnt to a crisp as the sun expands. Several years ago 20 ships were sent to search for new planets for humanity to move to. 13 have reported that they failed to find a suitable planet. The 14th has just reported that it succeeded.

Earth is governed by 20 ruling families, each of which owns huge companies. Each family has one vote within the council. The council needs to send at least one expedition to the new world to prepare it for the rest of humanity to follow. Each family wants their members to lead the expedition to get a better position in the new world.

### The Question

The players are all members of one family, and I want to run the council meeting in game. **How can I make it interesting?**

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately, this site does not handle broad idea generation questions like this, and it is likely to get closed until you can edit it to be more specific. One thing that might help is if you were to put details in of the specific issues you have faced when designing this kind of encounter before. What were the specific problems you want help with?

Comment: I have made some edits to your question to make it clearer. If you think that I have changed your meaning, then feel free to roll back the edits. I think this question is still in danger of being closed though, even with my edits.

Comment: To improve this question you need to describe your specific situation in a bit more detail as well as try to explain what sort of game you're playing. We do not generate ideas - but if you want to create a specific feeling (e.g. overwhelming sense of hostility) or situation (e.g. how to model betrayal in such a situation without railroading) we can definitely help - but your question needs to be specific and present an actual problem you're trying to address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the key to such a scene would be power imbalances. Your set up appears to go into a lot of effort to set up the families as all equal, my suggestion would be to make more disbalances.

Below is just one suggestion but you can fill other details instead:

1. You set up the 20 ships 20 houses idea, I am not sure if you meant to imply each house sent 1 ship or just by coincidence used the same number. That would be my first retcon.
2. Perhaps the family whose ship was successful would consider themselves the defacto leader, but are a less powerfull house.
3. There could be a faction of houses whose ships failed and rally behind one specific strong house as their leader, effectively living vicariously through him, as they will never have another opportunity to be "defacto" selected.
4. There could be a faction of houses whose ships haven't responded yet, perhaps they will push to remain on the planet and sabotage efforts to spend supplies on this inferior planet.